# Azure Functions V2 - BlobStorage FetchAttributes() Build issue

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have some functionality with Azure Function with a Event grid for blob events subscription. The code works fine in the V1 version.

net461
AnyCPU;x64

I am trying to modify it to the V2 (.NET Core) and surprisingly I am getting build error for the CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes(). I see only Async version is supported. I didn't find any documentation if the FetchAttributes() not supported with V2 version.

netstandard2.0
v2

I do have the necessary assembly references of  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob in the code.

**Error CS1061**    'CloudBlockBlob' does not contain a definition for 'FetchAttributes' and no extension method 'FetchAttributes' accepting a first argument of type 'CloudBlockBlob' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2017 as the IDE.

I would appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Standard version of Azure Storage libraries does not implement sync API:

> .NET Core team has chosen to not support a true sync api for the reasons listed above (resource consumption, etc.) Even if we implement a true sync, it would end up being sync over async at some level. For this reason, we believe that adding fake sync apis would be a hindrance and not a help to our customers.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367). At the end of the issue, there are some plans to support Sync API in future, but that's what we have now.

Azure Functions just use that library.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, that's really helpful!!